# Is it possible to subquery using SOSL?

Tags: salesforce, soql, force.com

I have a SOSL query that finds Salesforce Campaigns, and that's working just fine. However, I need to retrieve all Account Team Members for each returned Campaign. Is it possible to add a subquery to SOSL?

Here's what I have so far:

```
List<List<sObject>> searchList = 
    [FIND :CampaignSearchTerm RETURNING Campaign (Id Where IsActive = true Order By Name)];
```

If it is not possible, I have a different question. Can SOSL results be assigned to a Map or Set to avoid from having to put together all of the IDs in a for-loop for an SOQL query (for the sake of efficiency)?

Thanks!

Comment: Gah.. I don't think this is possible. Apparently there is no documentation on subquerying within SOSL (also, it didn't work when I tried), and the documentation on SOSL states that SOSL only returns data in List<List<sObject>> format. If anyone has a better solution, I'd be glad for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct :) But in terms of efficiency, SOSL is only bringing <= 200 results so producing Id lists for SOQL should have a negligible impact.

Comment: I ended up using a mix of SOSL and SOQL based on different conditions. Thanks for the reminder about the 200 record limit on SOSL.